# Looping through array of dates to find out if any of them match a date given

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, date

I need to check if a date value is equivalent to any dates in an array i have (including time value).

For some reason, when i loop through this array, angular will not let me use getTime. If i do use it, i get the error: element.start.getTime is not a function. As of right now, because the array dates and the newEvent I believe are in slightly different formats, the function always returns false even when there are equivalent dates.

Here is the function in question:

```
 seeIfAppStartExists(appStart: Date) {
      let ret = false;
      this.eventsArray.forEach(element => {
       // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
      if (element.start == appStart) {
            ret = true;
       }
   });

   return ret;

   }
```

Comment: Sounds like `element.start` is a string, not a Date object. Provide a runnable example as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you get the error “.getTime is not a function” when you call the getTime() function You need to use the **new** keyword to create a new object instance.

```
    let eventsArray = [{start : '2019-09-30T23:22:59.534Z'}, {start : '2019-11-30T23:22:59.534Z'}]
    function seeIfAppStartExists(appStart: Date) {
          let ret = false
          eventsArray.forEach(element => {
          let time = new Date(element.start)
          if (time.getTime() === appStart.getTime()) {
                ret = true;
           }
       });
       return ret;
    }

    console.log(seeIfAppStartExists(new Date('2019-09-30T23:22:59.534Z')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your implementation. Like the above answer says, you could use `new Date(element.start)` to actually get a date object. You can then call `getTime()` on that object and use it to compare. But the other problem with your logic is how you change the value of `ret` for each iteration. Essentially, your code will only tell you if the **last** element's start time matches your `appStart`. Because that is the one setting the value of `ret` at the end. All other values are going to be ignored.